# How to set recycle app pool setting in web.config C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

How to set recycle app pool every 12 hours in web.config? i know there is another do to it that is by setting it in the iis recycling condition. 
But i want to set the recycling app in web.config instead

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/), and it shows an example in a web.config too

[image]